# Liquibase DatabaseChangeLogTable

Tags: liquibase

There is a requirement in my project which requires more than one database change log table.
Multiple microservices are connecting with one Db instance having logical segregation of tables. We want that when Microservice-1 is making changes to the database there should be a separate DatabaseChangeLogTable so that when MS-1 tries to rollback no other MSs updates are rolledback.

Can somebody suggests is there provision for this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want multiple microservices connect to the same database, you have to options:

1. Use common `databasechangelog` table (it shouldn't be a problem if you write proper preConditions, since none of the changeSets will be executed if the preConditions are not met)
2. use another name for `databasechangelog` table by specifying `liquibase.databaseChangeLogTableName` property.

For the first microservice you may set:
`liquibase.databaseChangeLogTableName=databasechangelog_microservice_1`

For the second microservice you may set:
`liquibase.databaseChangeLogTableName=databasechangelog_microservice_2`

etc.

Note:

for Spring-boot this property will have a name `spring.liquibase.database-change-log-table=your_table_name`

And in case you want to change the name of `databasechangeloglock` table, use this property: `spring.liquibase.database-change-log-lock-table=your_lock_table_name`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not know how to set the property for it. Since, we have created an independent repository for the liquibase task. We had to do it because Spanner is supported by liquibase and we needed to write some code for by extending liquibase code. 
I have made changes in the "tags" column of the databasechangelog table. I have also tweeked the rollback implementation by overriding. Difference microservice will get a tag with its name in the end and incase of rollback only those microservice tags will be reverted.